# Why is the use of len(SEQUENCE) in condition values considered incorrect by Pylint?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, pylint

Considering this code snippet:

```
from os import walk

files = []
for (dirpath, _, filenames) in walk(mydir):
    # More code that modifies files
if len(files) == 0: # <-- C1801
    return None
```

I was alarmed by Pylint with this message regarding the line with the if statement:

> [pylint] C1801:Do not use `len(SEQUENCE)` as condition value

The rule C1801, at first glance, did not sound very reasonable to me, and the [definition on the reference guide](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide/features.html#id19) does not explain why this is a problem. In fact, it downright calls it an *incorrect use*.

> **len-as-condition (C1801)**:
> *Do not use `len(SEQUENCE)` as condition value Used when Pylint detects incorrect use of len(sequence) inside conditions.*

My search attempts have also failed to provide me a deeper explanation. I do understand that a sequence's length property may be lazily evaluated, and that `__len__` can be programmed to have side effects, but it is questionable whether that alone is problematic enough for Pylint to call such a use incorrect. Hence, before I simply configure my project to ignore the rule, I would like to know whether I am missing something in my reasoning.

When is the use of `len(SEQ)` as a condition value problematic? What major situations is Pylint attempting to avoid with C1801?

Comment: Because you can evaluate the truthiness of the sequence directly.  pylint wants you to do `if files:` or `if not files:`

Comment: `len` doesn't know the context in which it is called, so if computing the length means traversing the entire sequence, it must; it doesn't know that the result is just being compared to 0. Computing the boolean value can stop after it sees the first element, regardless of how long the sequence actually is. I think pylint is being a tad opinionated here, though; I can't think of any situation where it is *wrong* to use `len`, just that it's a worse option than the alternative.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thank you, Pylint was indeed telling me to write `if not files:`, although it did not tell me that. How could one ever guess other than know all pythonic idioms in advance?

Comment: @E_net4 I think that [PEP-8](http://pep8.org/) is probably the place to start.

Comment: @E_net4 [I've submitted an issue about not giving reasonable suggestion as a potential enhancement on Pylint's GitHub](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1405).

Comment: SEQUENCES need an 'empty()' or 'isempty()' like C++ imo.

Comment: Because the supposed alternative, testing for truthiness, has the unintended consequences of being "always true" if the `__bool__` function isn't defined.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

> When is the use of `len(SEQ)` as a condition value problematic? What major
>   situations is Pylint attempting to avoid with C1801?

It’s not *really* problematic to use `len(SEQUENCE)` – though it may not be as efficient (see [chepner’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121340/why-is-the-use-of-lensequence-in-condition-values-considered-incorrect-by-pyli#comment73322508_43121340)). Regardless, Pylint checks code for compliance with the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) which states that

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.
>
> ```
> Yes: if not seq:
>      if seq:
>
> No:  if len(seq):
>      if not len(seq):
> ```

As an occasional Python programmer, who flits between languages, I’d consider the `len(SEQUENCE)` construct to be more readable and explicit (“Explicit is better then implicit”).  However, using the fact that an empty sequence evaluates to `False` in a Boolean context is considered more “Pythonic”.

Comment: How to make this work then: `if len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(os.getcwd()), 'f_*')):`

Comment: @Marichyasana I guess things like that can (theoretically) be written as `if next(iter(...), None) is not None:` (if the sequence can't contain `None`). That's long, but the `len(fnmatch...)` is long too; both need to be split.

Comment: I'm also an occassional Python user and often I have the impression that the "Pythonic way" got kind of tangled in its own ambiguity.

Comment: Just a general question, can these PEP recommendations be revised? Another reason why the `len(s) == 0` is superior in my opinion is that it is generalizable for other types of sequences. For example, `pandas.Series` and numpy arrays. `if not s:` is not on the other hand, and in that case you would need to use a separate evaluation for all possible types of arrays-like objects (i.e `pd.DataFrame.empty`).

Comment: By the way, none `of collections.abc` classes states `__bool__` method. In other words, how can I be sure that I can use `bool(seq)` if I know that it's a `collections.abc.Collection`? Moreso, some libraries declire that it's forbidden to check `bool(collection)` for their classes.

Comment: I don't like the truthy recommendations because they silently allow type errors to go through.

Comment: The PEP recommends against `if len(x)`.  It does **not** recommend against `if len(x) > 0`.

Answer (score 46):

Note that the use of `len(seq)` is in fact required (instead of just checking the bool value of `seq`) when using NumPy arrays.

```py
a = numpy.array(range(10))
if a:
    print("a is not empty")
```

results in an exception:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And hence for code that uses both Python lists and NumPy arrays, the C1801 message is less than helpful.

Comment: I agree with your statement. With [issue #1405](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1405) now raised, I hope to see C1801 either reformed to something useful or disabled by default.

Comment: plus it is useless for checking if a sequence has a given number of elements. It's only good for checking it it is completely empty in the best of cases.

Answer (score 9):

This was a issue in Pylint, and it no longer considers `len(x) == 0` as incorrect.

You should not use a **bare** `len(x)` as a condition.  Comparing `len(x)` against an explicit value, such as `if len(x) == 0` of `if len(x) > 0` is totally fine and not prohibited by PEP 8.

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> ```
> # Correct:
> if not seq:
> if seq:
>
> # Wrong:
> if len(seq):
> if not len(seq):
> ```

Note that **explicitly testing for the length** is not prohibited. The [Zen of Python](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2815) states:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

In the choice between `if not seq` and `if not len(seq)`, both are implicit, but the behaviour is different. But `if len(seq) == 0` or `if len(seq) > 0` are explicit comparisons and are in many contexts the correct behaviour.

In Pylint, [PR 2815](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/2815) has fixed this bug, first reported as [issue 2684](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2684). It will continue to complain about `if len(seq)`, but it will no longer complain about `if len(seq) > 0`.  The PR was merged 2019-03-19, so if you are using Pylint 2.4 (released 2019-09-14) or newer, you should not see this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Pylint was failing for my code and research led me to this post:

```
../filename.py:49:11: C1801: Do not use `len(SEQUENCE)` to determine if a sequence is empty (len-as-condition)
../filename.py:49:34: C1801: Do not use `len(SEQUENCE)` to determine if a sequence is empty (len-as-condition)
```

This was my code before:

```
def list_empty_folders(directory):
"""The Module Has Been Build to list empty Mac Folders."""
for (fullpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
    if len(dirnames) == 0 and len(filenames) == 0:
        print("Exists: {} : Absolute Path: {}".format(
            os.path.exists(fullpath), os.path.abspath(fullpath)))
```

This was after my code fix.  By using the `int()` `attribute`, I seem to have satisfied the Pep8/Pylint and doesn't seem to have a negative impact on my code:

```
def list_empty_folders(directory):
"""The Module Has Been Build to list empty Mac Folders."""
for (fullpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
    if len(dirnames).__trunc__() == 0 and len(filenames).__trunc__() == 0:
        print("Exists: {} : Absolute Path: {}".format(
            os.path.exists(fullpath), os.path.abspath(fullpath)))
```

### My Fix

By adding `.__trunc__()` to the sequence it seems to have settled the need.

I do not see a difference in the behaviour, but if anyone knows specifics that I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: You are calling `__trunc__()` on the output of `len(seq)`, which (somewhat redundantly) truncates the length value to an integer. It only "feints" the lint without addressing the reason behind it. Didn't the suggestion in the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: Not in my attempts. I understand the redundancy, but even after this issue has been addressed by the developers in https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1405 & 2684 and has been merged in, to my understanding this shouldn't be an issue when running pylint but I still see this issue even after updating my pylint.  I Just wanted to share, as `this worked for me`, even if it isn't entirely appropriate.  But, to clarify even if it is redundant if you are doing a len(seq) == 0 comparison, __trunc__ shouldn't have to do anything as they are already integers. right?

Comment: Exactly, it is already an integer, and `__trunc__()` doesn't do anything meaningful. Note that I did not refer to the comparison as being redundant, but to this attempt at truncating the length. The warning only disappears because it only expects an expression of the form `len(seq) == 0`. I believe that the lint in this case would expect you to replace the if statement with the following: `if not dirnames and not filenames:`

Comment: Testing for truthiness has the unintended consequences of being "always true" if the `__bool__` function isn't defined in the underlying sequence.