# while loop with iterator in python which keeps on changing

Tags: python

I have a snippet where I need to iterate over a list of items and remove the item whose job is done and continue looping on the remaining items.

as per python I can pass `l` to check condition for `while` loop as below :-

```
l = [node1, node2, node3]
while l:
    #do something
    for t in l:
        if t[wt] > 10:
            l.remove(t)
```

but as per [this guide](https://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make), it is not a good practice to modify a list while iterating over it.

So I changed my code to :-

```
l = [node1, node2, node3]
while len(l)>0:
    #do something
    for t in l:
        if t[wt] > 10:
            l.remove(t)
```

But then I see below pylint warning :-

> [pylint] C1801:Do not use len(SEQUENCE) as condition value :- [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121340/why-is-the-use-of-lensequence-in-condition-values-considered-incorrect-by-pyli)

Now what should be the approach here to handle this `while` loop with `list` which would not violate any of the above practices ?

Comment: `while l` and `while len(l) > 0'`mean exactly the same: the only list that evaluates to `False` in boolean context is the empty list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I would request you to kindly go through the whole query again.

Comment: @Jean-François. please go through the problem statement before marking duplicate.

Comment: ok, I really misread because of the inner loop. Reopened, and edited my answer

Comment: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: yes, but here OP got fooled/didn't see the mixup between the while loop and the inner for loop.

Comment: @PabitraPati Your two versions of the code do exactly the same, the fact that Pylint gives a warning for the style of the second version doesn't change that. The problem remains the same: you remove items of the list while iterating over it. In short, you can replace the whole for loop by `l = [t for t in l if t[wt] <= 10]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `len(l)` in your condition, you didn't improve your code, it remains with the same error (removing items while iterating in the inner `for` loop), you just degraded the code, adding an irrelevant warning.

You are still removing elements while iterating in the inner loop.

```
for t in l:
    if t[wt] > 10:
        l.remove(t)
```

This could induce a subtle bug: if 2 consecutive elements need to be removed, the second one is skipped, and your code executes twice the processing you've eluded before the loop.

Instead, you should recompute `l` in the end using a list comprehension

```
l = [node1, node2, node3]
while l:
   # do something then rebuild `l` 
   l = [t for t in l if t[wt] <= 10]
```

more about this: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Finally a new picture, +1

Comment: ah you noticed :)

Comment: Oh, I hadn't, I feel sooo sorry :)

Comment: I just hope not to get votes only because I changed my picture :)